# Why my First Load Js is in red? I am using next.js 13 with app router

Tags: reactjs, routes, dynamic, next.js13

[image]

I want some suggestion, like why this can happen. Or what I can try to reduce this.
Thank You.

Below file is page.tsx inside [...slug] folder, which handles all dynamic routes.

```
import React from 'react';

import Page404 from './Page404';
import { fetchContentPage, fetchContentType } from '@/api/common';
import { valArrLength } from '@/helpers/commonHelper';
import ContentPage from '@/Components/Common/ContentPage/ContentPage';
import { genPageMetaData, genSplitedUrls } from '@/api/helper/common';

export default async function DyanmicPage({
    params,
}: {
    params: { slug: Array<string> };
}) {
    const path = params?.slug?.join('/');
    const pageData = await fetchContentPage(path);

    if (valArrLength(pageData?.data)) {
        return <ContentPage data={pageData.data[0]} />;
    } else {
        return <Page404 />;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a very large chunk of javascript to client to be able to render this page.

Part of the point of Next is to allocate as much logic as posible on the server, sending html and css instead of javascript to create them.

It looks like you are doing all your application logic client side. Checks if you have `use client` directive on top of your file. If so, consider refactor it to do things like data fetching in server instead of wait javascript to load on the client to do it.

Comment: Hi @raul-calvo, I have added my page.tsx please check above. I am not using 'use client' in my top level components.